# Can the days reputation be added up and displayed next to the 'Today'/'Yesterday'/etc. label on the SO app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Sometimes I am out on the road and am wondering how much reputation I have accumulated today or in a day. Currently I have to add line by line to see how I have increased/decreased. Can a total number tally be added to the SO app next to the "Today" label?

Placed here or something:

[image: Something like this]